# facing issue in new symfony version 5.4

Tags: pimcore, php-8.1, symfony5.4

I have updated existing project to pimcore 10.6.7 and symfony 5.4, php v 8.1
after updating facing error.

when i open existing templates from the admin interface, getting error of default doest not exist as service or class

please find the below screenshot.
[image]

[image]

Please suggest me to solve the issue

Thanks in advance